# IdentityServer4 Js Client token security for WebApi(s) Hybrid Vs Implicit GrantTypes

Tags: authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, browser-security

Hi I have been looking at IdentityServer4 for my ASP.NET Core Web API and JS client. I refer to the [official documentation here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/index.html).

This is what I want to do. I want to have 3 hosts:

1. IdentityServer
2. Asp.net core MVC Web API
3. Javascript client that will call the API

I realize that I can have a client with grant type `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,` which is supposedly more secure. If I used this client with the web api, the access tokens will not go though the browser channel but through a so called 'backend channel' and i can authenticate an authorize controller actions using custom authorization.

On the other hand it seams that in order to have a js client that accesses the API through API calls, I need to have `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit` which will expose the access token through the browser.

The issue is that I want to use claims in the user context submitted to the API to authorize access to specific controller actions. The presence or absence of such claims will indicate whether a logged-in user is allowed to access an action. I am hoping the 'backend channel' the Hybrid grant type provides protects the injection of claims by hackers. I don't want to have to recheck the validity of the claims received in the user context.

Because of these concerns, I am thinking of forgetting about the JS client and just implementing the MVC web application on the same host as the API since this is much the same in ASP.NET Core (if you know what I mean - see Shawn Wildermuth's PluralSight course on [Building a WebAppp with ASP.net Core, MVC6, EF Core and Angular](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnetcore-efcore-bootstrap-angular-web-app/table-of-contents))

I am assuming using the `Implicit` grant type exposes too many security risks?
  Am I wrong?  Is there a secure 'backend channel' of communicating with the JS API?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You want to watch this: https://vimeo.com/131636653

Comment: @flexxxit I am in the same scenario that you described here. What ended up being the answer/solution?